Keycloak admin client 24.0.3 keycloak builder HTTP 404 or 400
    keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8084")  // 404:without /auth   400:with /auth
            .realm( "my-group-dev")
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .clientId("realm-management")
            .clientSecret("NOVguUuH29TyB5B8zWy8u79OMAkdvy26")
            .build();
    keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();

I've just upgraded keycloak and keycloak admin client to 24.0.3 from 17.0.1.
Not sure why I keep getting error, it worked when I used 17.0.1
Could someone help me?
Btw: originally I used "ream-management" to do all the keycloak-java thing for my own client "waste-water", it all worked fine.

serverUrl /auth and no /auth
clientId use real UUID

look up a lot of articles and read docs.


My solution:

add a new client "admin"



Assign all the necessary roles to "Service accounts roles" tab




